# React Native elements not rerendering after state change

Tags: typescript, react-native, redux

I have been looking at this error for 2 days now, and I cannot seem to figure out how and why this is not working. I have a `FlatList` of `ProductComponent` elements in my app which can be bought and sold through the push on a `TouchableHighlight` component defined in the `ProductComponent`.
Below is the code of my `FlatList` component and the `ProductComponent` it renders:

The `FlatList` component:

```js
    const ProductList: React.FC = () => {
    const energyResources = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.energyResources).asImmutable();
    const dispatch = useDispatch<RootDispatch>();
    const coins = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.coins).coins;

    const purchaseItem = (item: IEnergyResource): void => {
        if (coins > item.price) {
            dispatch.energyResources.increaseAmountOwned(dispatch.energyResources, item);
            dispatch.coins.buy(dispatch.coins, item.price);

            Alert.alert(
                'Gekocht!',
                'Je hebt zojuist de energiebron ' + item.name + ' gekocht, ' +
                '\nJe hebt nu nog €' + coins + ' Euro!'
            );
        } else {
            Alert.alert(
                'Niet gekocht',
                'Sorry, je hebt niet genoeg geld om deze energiebron te kopen.'
            );
        }
    };

    const sellItem = (item: IEnergyResource): void => {
        if (item.amountOwned > 0) {
            dispatch.energyResources.decreaseAmountOwned(dispatch.energyResources, item);
            dispatch.coins.sell(dispatch.coins, item.price);

            Alert.alert(
                'Verkocht!',
                'De energiebron ' + item.name + ' is verkocht, ' +
                'je hebt nu €' + coins + ' Euro.'
            );
        }  else {
            Alert.alert(
                'Niet verkocht',
                'Sorry, de energiebron ' + item.name + ' kon niet worden verkocht, ' +
                'je hebt er geen in je bezit.'
            );
        }
    };

    return (
        <FlatList
            style={styles.list}
            data={energyResources.toArray()}
            renderItem={
                ({ item }) => <ProductComponent
                    resource={item}
                    onPurchase={purchaseItem}
                    onSell={sellItem}
                    canSell={item.amountOwned > 0}
                />
            }
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.name}
        />
    );
}
```

Both the purchase and sell methods are defined in the `FlatList`-component, and then passed to the individual elements (I figured this was better than defining the functions in `ProductComponent` itself and having each rendered item call on the state).

The `ProductComponent` component:

```js
export interface IProductProps {
    resource: IEnergyResource;
    onPurchase: Function;
    onSell: Function;
    canSell: boolean;
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    buttonRight: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        alignSelf: 'flex-end',
        backgroundColor: Constants.Colors.DodgerBlue,
        marginVertical: 5,
        padding: 10,
        width: 150
    },
    image: {
        alignSelf: 'flex-start',
        height: 100,
        width: 100
    },
    listItem: {
        borderBottomColor: Constants.Colors.Blue,
        borderBottomWidth: 2,
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        marginLeft: 5,
        marginBottom: 0,
        paddingBottom: 5
    },
    productInfo: {
        width: 300,
    },
    rightButtons: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        alignSelf: 'flex-end'
    },
    sell: {
        backgroundColor: Constants.Colors.Red
    },
    textLeft: {
        alignSelf: 'flex-start',
        fontSize: 20,
    }
});

const ProductComponent: React.FC<IProductProps> = (props) => {

    return (
        <View style={styles.listItem}>
            <Image source={props.resource.image.image} width={50} height={50} style={styles.image} />
            <View style={styles.productInfo}>
                <Text style={styles.textLeft}>{props.resource.name}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.textLeft}>€{props.resource.price}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.textLeft}>Energiewaarde: {props.resource.energyValue} Watt</Text>
                <Text style={styles.textLeft}>In bezit: {props.resource.amountOwned}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.rightButtons}>
                <TouchableHighlight style={styles.buttonRight} onPress={() => props.onPurchase(props.resource)}>
                    {/* eslint-disable-next-line react-native/no-inline-styles */}
                    <Text style={{ color: Constants.Colors.White, fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 15 }}>Kopen</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>
                <TouchableHighlight style={[styles.buttonRight, styles.sell]} disabled={props.canSell} onPress={() => props.onSell(props.resource)}>
                    {/* eslint-disable-next-line react-native/no-inline-styles */}
                    <Text style={{ color: Constants.Colors.White, fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 15 }}>Verkopen</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
};
```

The methods are present in the IProductProps interface and the calls seem to work (I am getting the defined `Alert` as though I have indeed purchased a product). However, after clicking *OK* in the alertbox, the counter for the specified product (defined in `ProductComponent` as `props.resource.amountOwned`) remains 0 and I am unable to sell that same product.

These are the methods defined in the state models which I am calling:

```js
/**
 * Increases the amount of items the player owns.
 *
 * @param {List<IEnergyResource>} state - the current state of the app
 * @param {IEnergyResource} item - the item which was bought
 * @returns {List<IEnergyResource>} state
 */
function increaseAmountOwned(state: EnergyResourcesState, item: IEnergyResource): EnergyResourcesState {
    const itemIndex = state.indexOf(item);
    const newItem = {
        amountOwned: item.amountOwned++,
        ...item
    };

    return state.set(itemIndex, newItem);
}

/**
 * Decreases the amount of items the player owns.
 *
 * @param {List<IEnergyResource>} state - The current state of the app
 * @param {IEnergyResource} item - the item which was sold
 * @returns {List<IEnergyResource>} state
 */
function decreaseAmountOwned(state: EnergyResourcesState, item: IEnergyResource): EnergyResourcesState {
    const itemIndex = state.indexOf(item);
    const newItem = {
        amountOwned: item.amountOwned--,
        ...item
    } as IEnergyResource;

    return state.set(itemIndex, newItem);
}

const initialState: IEnergyResource[] =
    [
        {
            name:'Windmolen',
            price: 15,
            energyValue:20,
            environmentValue:-15,
            image:{

                maxSize:{
                    width:0.2,
                    height:0.2,
                },
                image: images.windmill,
            },
            amountOwned: 0,
            amountTotal: 30,
            amountPlaced: 0,
            location:{
                x:0.05,
                y:0
            },
        },{
            name:'Watermolen',
            price: 15,
            energyValue:15,
            environmentValue:-10,
            image:{

                maxSize:{
                    width:0.2,
                    height:0.2,
                },
                image: images.turbine
            },
            amountOwned: 0,
            amountTotal: 30,
            amountPlaced: 0,
            location:{
                x:0.05,
                y:0.3
            },
        },{
            name:'Zonnepaneel',
            price: 15,
            energyValue:10,
            environmentValue:-5,
            image:{

                maxSize:{
                    width:0.2,
                    height:0.2,
                },
                image: images.solarPanel
            },
            amountOwned: 0,
            amountTotal: 30,
            amountPlaced: 0,
            location:{
                x:0.3,
                y:0
            },
        }
    ]

const resources = {
    state: List(initialState),
    reducers: {
        place:(state: EnergyResourcesState, name: string): EnergyResourcesState =>
            state = doMutateEnergyResource(state, name, true),
        remove:(state: EnergyResourcesState, name: string): EnergyResourcesState =>
            state = doMutateEnergyResource(state, name, false),
        increaseAmountOwned: increaseAmountOwned,
        decreaseAmountOwned: decreaseAmountOwned
    },
};
```

I am using [Rematch Redux framework](https://github.com/rematch/rematch) to work with the state.

It is probably a minor detail I am overlooking here, so any help or nudges in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: My guess would be that in `increaseAmountOwned` the `energyResources` array is being updated but not recreated. The selector will probably do a shallow comparision and bail if the array reference is not changed. Can check for sure if you post the code for `increaseAmountOwned`.

Comment: @nipuna777 the code for `increaseAmountOwned` is already present as far as I can see, it is the first function in the last code block!

Comment: Got it. I must've missed that earlier. I see that you are using a `List` to store the state, which library does that use? Have you tried using an array instead? Also, to debug this, I would first set a few more breakpoints(or alerts) to see if the reducers, and the render method gets called again. If you can make a minimum reproducable demo on stackblitz or some similar site, I can help debug this further.

Comment: Thank you for the help @nipuna777! I found the problem now (see the answer). Someone else in my project group was responsible for programming the state managers, and he used `List`-objects everywhere. I do not know why either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I had misunderstood how the Rematch Reducers work in relation to the state. They are to be seen as extension methods to the defined state (`resources` in this case). As can be seen in the reducer definitions, a reducer takes two parameters; the current state and whatever change to be made.

It was my understanding that I would need to provide the state as it stands in the currently active view (the `FlatList` in this instance) for the user, like so:

```js
 dispatch.energyResources.increaseAmountOwned(dispatch.energyResources, item);
```

This turned out to be my mistake, as the `state` parameter is supplied by Rematch in the background when the method is called. The method needs to be called like so:

```js
 dispatch.energyResources.increaseAmountOwned(item);
```

Rematch will notice the `increaseAmountOwned()` call and inject the current state existing in `dispatch.energyResources` into the method before executing.